# Asp.Net Core 3.1 produces .exe file that can't be deleted

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core 3.1 web api (running in IIS) that I've built that produces a .exe file.  I'm using OutOfProcess hosting model.

Recently it's started becoming impossible to remove and replace, no matter what is done.

Previously we used an app_offline.htm file, which should disable the app and allow the entire folder to be cleared out, but it looks like no matter what's done the .exe file is never allowed to be deleted, even disabling the IIS app pool or website doesn't do it.

Comment: Is it running as a service?   Can you manually stop the service?

Answer (score 0):

The Out-Of-Process hosting model even if is set to run under IIS in fact the IIS HTTP Server won't be used. Instead Kestrel web server is used to process your requests. So, ASP.NET Core Module forwards your requests to Kestrel web server. For more details about InProcess and OutOfProcess there is a nice article [here](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/bb086279-ed2a-4628-85f2-7e91125fbe57.aspx).

Open powershell and try to kill all instances of the kestral server like this:

```
Get-Process -Name *dotnet* | Stop-Process
```